# Autowired bean is null in component class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have created RestTemplate Bean in main class and injected this bean in another class of different package by using @Autowired.When I try to use it is null.

**Main class:
package :com.ff.filter**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.ff"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class CcFilterSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CcFilterSearchApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    }
```

package where I have injected bean :**com.ff.filter.friendlist**

```
    @Component
    public class CustomFriendList {


        @Autowired
        RestTemplate restTemplate;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            System.out.println("inti  "+restTemplate);
        }

        public List<String> blockedList(String userId) throws JSONException {

            System.out.println("restTemplate   "+restTemplate);

        }
}
```

When i call this(blockedList) method restTemplate is printing null.Anyone one please help.

Comment: And what does `@PostContruct` print?

Comment: @Alan Hay In post construct its printing object

Comment: The answer given is most likely correct then. You are calling the method on a new instance and not the Spring managed instance.

Comment: @nithin Are you calling `init` by hand or Spring does tht for you ??

Comment: I am calling method by creating new Instance so it is null.I have @Autowired CustomFriendList then its working.

Answer (score 1):

If the `CustomFriendList` component is not initialized by the Spring mechanism, i.e. because it is created via `new CustomFriendList()` the `RestTemplate` member is not autowired and therefore `null`.

You might want [to create](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web) a `@SpringBootTest`, inject the component and then test the functionality.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void blockedList(CustomFriendList friendList) throws Exception {
        List<String> blocked = friendList.blockedList("testUserId");
        blocked.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: .I have @Autowired CustomFriendList then its working

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired
CustomFriendList customFriendList;

Instead of creating new object Autowire bean then its working